# How to repack a JSON String?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, replace, fancybox

### JSON Wildcard Replace Value

My purpose is to add a dynamic values inside my fancybox and I have to generate a JSON that is fetched from the database..

Here is my current code inside a model in Code Igniter:

```
     function get_gallery_list($album) {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, img_name, caption FROM tb_gallery WHERE album = "'.$album.'"');
        $tags = array('img_name', 'caption');
        $replacementTags = array('html', 'title');
        $json = str_replace($tags, $replacementTags, json_encode($query->result()));
        $search_array = array_fill(0, sizeof($replacements), $search_pattern);
        $result = preg_replace($search_array, $replacements, $subject, 1);
        return $json;
     }

    //img_name is replace with html, caption = title.
    /* returns: [{"id":"1","html":"roadshow2012_1.jpg","title":"WOW"},{"id":"2","html":"roadshow2012_1.jpg","title":"Wew"}] */
```

### My question is that, How can I add values inside the ".jpg" values?

Example:

#### From "roadshow2012_1.jpg" to "directlink-to-localhost/images/gallery/roadshow2012/roadshow2012_1.jpg"

Advanced thanks for those who will answer!:D

Comment: try doing it before you `json_encode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't do that when you can do this instead. It's less work and easier for others to follow

```
$sql='SELECT id, 
        CONCAT("directlink-to-localhost/images/gallery/",img_name) AS html, 
        caption AS title 
    FROM tb_gallery 
    WHERE album = "'.$album.'"';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return json_encode($query->result());
```

...

I shouldn't really post how to do it the way you asked because it's a bit mad but if you must...

You're using preg_replace for no good reason when str_replace is much faster.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, img_name, caption FROM tb_gallery WHERE album = "'.$album.'"');
$find = array('"img_name":"', '"caption"');
$replace = array('"html":"directlink-to-localhost/images/gallery/', '"title"');
$result=str_replace($find, $replace, json_encode($query->result());
return $json;
```

I can't see the db class so have assumed that query->result() does what you expect.